# pygame.error: No available audio device

Tags: audio, pygame

I'm using Raspberry Pi 3b, usb mic and 3.5mm audio jack as speaker. mic is hw:1,0; speaker is hw:0,0

Everything works fine except that I'm unable to get `pygame.mixer.Sound.play()` in a python script to work.

Script:

```
import time
import pygame
pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()
sounda=pygame.mixer.Sound("test.wav")
sounda.play()
```

I get:

```
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1052:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
pygame.error: No available audio device
```

or `MemoryError`

However if I enter python2&3 environment then run the commands again, it worked fine...
Appreciate the help.

Comment: it is possible that you are running python 2 for one of the tests and python 3 for the other test

Comment: just entered python3 environment, and it worked too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally made this work.

Check your `alsa.conf` and `.asoundrc` file, only one of them needs to be configured with your audio setup.

I setup my audio in both files which caused the confusion, once I restored alsa.conf to default, the problem is gone.